# How to send html in postman body

Tags: c#, html

I want to be in the body of postman Inside one property To enter tag html But Postman gives an error Even when content type I change it from json to html It gives an error again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwOhd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCN9t.png)com/PCjOu.png

Thank you if anyone solves my problem

Comment: Careful with those quotes. It looks like JSON but is invalid. You will need to escape the quotes in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes `"` need escaping as `\"`

```
"text": "<p><img class="img-responsive" src="the-url" alt="the alt" style="the styles"><p>"
```

should be

```
"text": "<p><img class=\"img-responsive\" src=\"the-url\" alt=\"the alt\" style=\"the styles\"><p>"
```

Comment: The sentence I have is about 500 lines. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Is the string coming in from a program? In C# you could use `s = s.Replace("\"", "\\\"");` or in JavaScript you could use `s = s.replace(/"/g, '\\"');`